# Android Studio newly created library module cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android

I decided to extract some functionality from my project into a separate module so I used Android Studio's wizard to create new module (Android Library module).

One of the classes uses a string resource, but when I try to use it, it cannot recognize `R`. Importing `com.example.mylib.*;` doesn't help, neither does sync project, make project, clean project, rebuild project, invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Check you string resource is their anything written like for e.g `can't` with desk in word ? Show your `Gradle` Log.

Comment: share the build error logs

Comment: There's no problem with the Strings and the only errors in the build are being unable to resolve R

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that in my `build.gradle` I only had a `release` flavor, and somehow the `BuildVariants` window had inherited the `debug` option set for the newly created module. When I switched to `release`, `R` was now visible.

Answer (score 0):

try **invalidate catches/restart**...

hope this will help you..